# Unable to update checkbox with true value

Tags: acumatica, jaas, myob

Trying to make a customized checkbox to stay true for all newly created documents.
Attributes:
`[PXDBBool()] [PXDefault(TRUE)] [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update Projects")]`

ASPX:
`<px:PXCheckBox CommitChanges="True" ID="edUpdateProject" runat="server" DataField="UpdateProject" ></px:PXCheckBox>`

Comment: Please provide full DAC class so that we can better understand the problem. Also, if this is an extension, make sure to follow standard Acumatica naming convention for field names.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this **[PXDefault(true)]**. make true as small letters.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for one of my customizations. This code may help you.

```
  #region Status
    [PXDBBool()]
    [PXDefault(true,PersistingCheck =PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active")]
    public virtual bool? Status { get; set; }
    public abstract class status : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<status> { }
    #endregion
```